# Place DataGridView''s row indicator for manually selected row

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code in a WinForms datagridview for handling right-mouse-clicks to select the underlying row:

```
private void dataGridViewTestSteps_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right) return;

        var hitTestInfo = dataGridViewTestSteps.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        dataGridViewTestSteps.ClearSelection();
        dataGridViewTestSteps.Rows[hitTestInfo.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
```

... now this works fine, but it does not place the small indicator in the correct row (see image below). So basically I was wondering what's missing in the method above?

[image: falsely placed row indicator]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The row header cursor shows the current row, not the selected row - they are actually different, since you can have multiple selected rows but only one current row.

Try this code instead:

```
private void dataGridViewTestSteps_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right) return;

    var hitTestInfo = dataGridViewTestSteps.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    //dataGridViewTestSteps.ClearSelection();
    //dataGridViewTestSteps.Rows[hitTestInfo.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    dataGridViewTestSteps.CurrentCell = dataGridViewTestSteps.Rows[hitTestInfo.RowIndex].Cells[0];
}
```